# How to header image / banner that expand to video on play button click?

Tags: youtube, html5-video

I want to create a header image / banner that, when a play image is clicked, expands vertically to play a video hosted on YouTube.

This page shows exactly what I'm trying to do:
[blendedlearningnow.com/about](http://www.blendedlearningnow.com/about).

I'm not sure if this is a function available through the JWPlayer or some other code.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that this is functionality inside JWPlayer. You could do it with jquery and .slideDown() http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I'll take a look. I think I'm going to have to deconstruct what's on the example site. I'm not really a coder, but, like many, I decode and follow examples. I just really like this effect of appearing to be a banner, sliding open the player, and then playing the video.